# Returning a variable from a coroutine in Kotlin with Room Database

Tags: android, database, android-jetpack-compose, android-room

Hi there and thank you for considering my question.  My app has Room running fine (finally) and I want to return the value of myVal2 from the following code.

From my Repository:

```
fun getFindTotal(): Double {
var myVal: Double  = 8008.5 
coroutineScope.launch (Dispatchers.IO){
var myVal2=findDao.getFindTotal()
Log.i("myVal2","$myVal2") 
      }
return myVal // Would like to return myVal2 not myVal
}
```

I want to return myVal2 not myVal.  I created the variable myVal to test to see if a double is passed successfully to my UI, and it does.  When I look at Logcat for myVal2, the value is correct, the SQL query is working perfectly.  How can I return the value of myVAl2?

Again, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should use runBlocking, cause you are not using suspending function. You can use it like below:

```
    fun getFindTotal(): Double {
    val result = runBlocking {
        findDao.getFindTotal()
    }
    return result
}
```

But instead of using your repository to execute your dao functions, you should consider executing in your ViewModel class. It is much better way than this and you could use background threads more effectively with coroutines like `viewModelScope` .